# How can I pass argument when click term link to a view page?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views

I have 2 vocabularies "brand" and color".  The contents can have multiple terms from "Color" which is hierarchical taxonomy and just one term from "Brand" 
For example,

```
 <Color>
    -Dark
      -Blak
      -Grey
      -Brown
    -Vivid
      -Bule
      -Yellow

 <Brand>
    -GM
    -BMW
    -Honda
```

I would like to override the links on the node view`taxonomy/term/tid` to my costom view page `cars/%/%/view`. the first argument is "Color" and the second argument is "Brand"
Then I would like to link them like this for example:

When the node is tagged with `Dark,Black,Grey,Brown and GM`
On the node view if users click `"Dark"` it will take them to `cars/tid(Dark)/tid(GM)/view`,
if users click `"Black"` it will take them to `cars/tid(Black)/tid(GM)/view`

After reading [this article](http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/link-taxonomy-terms-custom-views-drupal) I made a new term view which display the terms tagged with the node being viewed and then put it in node template file. I also delete the default `<?php print $terms ?>` from the template file.I set two "excluded from display" views fields for the new term view:

```
`taxonomy:term ID` with relationship `taxonomy:Terms on node (Color)`

`taxonomy:term ID` with relationship `taxonomy:Terms on node (Brand)`
```

And then set "Output this field as a link" for the term field of "Color" with tokens like this:

```
cars/[tid]/[tid_1]/view
```

So the tokens are meaning: `[tid]=tid of "Color"  and    [tid_1]=tid of "Brand"`

OK, finally when we click one of the terms of "Color" on node view, tid of "Color" of the output links are not correct.  For example:
On a node tagged with `Dark,Black,Grey,Brown and GM`
when click `"Black"`  takes to

```
 cars/[tid of some other color]/[tid of GM]/view
```

but what I expect is

```
cars/[tid of Black]/[tid of GM]/view
```

How can I achieve this?
Thank you for reading this long example.